# Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'Date'

Tags: swift

In playgrounds this code works great and I get the expected output exactly as I want, but when I go put it in my Xcode project I get 3 warning with my **startDate** saying

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'Date'

Here is my code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, dd yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "June, 27 2018")

    if let date = date {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

        var startDate : Date = Date()
        var interval : TimeInterval = 0

        if calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: date) {
            print(startDate)
            let daysToAdd = 6
            var dateComponent = DateComponents()

            dateComponent.day = daysToAdd

            let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: startDate)

            let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "MMMM dd-"
            let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
            let startWeek = dateFormatter1.string(from: startDate)
            dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd"
            let endWeek = dateFormatter2.string(from: futureDate!)
            results = "\(startWeek)\(endWeek)"
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What line gets the warning?

Comment: I copied your exact code into an Xcode 9.4.1 Swift playground I get no such error. Please post code that actually causes your issue.

Comment: Yeah In swift playgrounds I don't get the error, but like I said when I add it to mu project I do. I posted a screenshot of the error

Comment: What is the Xcode version? What is the Swift version? Don't you have your own class/struct that is also called `Date`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The green text color on `Date` type in

```
var startDate : Date = Date()
```

means that you have your own class/struct that is called `Date`. That one cannot be converted to `Foundation.Date`.

It's not a good idea to create this kind of name conflict in the first place but you can fix it just using the full name:

```
var startDate = Foundation.Date()
```

Comment: The error message is not clear in this case and I wonder if we should report a bug because the error would be much clearer if it contained the full qualified name of both types.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = Date()
```

I had the same issue and I fixed that with the code above. hope works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate this issue with an example.

This will produce the error, because while I did want to return a Date in the Result object, I didn't need to create a generic called Date at the interface for this function.  That was my mistake.

```
func daysAgo<Date>(_ dayCount: Int) -> Result<Date, CommonErrors> {
    let date: Date? = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dayCount, to: self)
    return Result(success: date, failure: .initFailed)
}
```

The following code solves my issue:

```
func daysAgo(_ dayCount: Int) -> Result<Date, CommonErrors> {
   let date: Date? = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dayCount, to: self)
   return Result(success: date, failure: .initFailed)
}
```